# Work on every record sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, i am new to microsoft sql server.

I have a table with the name `login credentials`

```
id | name | l_date  | status
1  | aa   |1.2.2017 | active
```

So what i have to do is to find the ones who have the difference of 3 months in their date with the current date and set them to inactive.

example: 
above l_date is `1.2.2017` and current is `12.09.2017` , there is a three month gap , so set it to inactive.

What i tried.

```
USE databasename
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.datediffer 
AS
DECLARE @LastChangeDate as date
declare @current as date
declare @datediffernce as int


DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR;
DECLARE @MyField ;
BEGIN
    SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FOR
    select *  from dbo.table_name

    OPEN @MyCursor 
    FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
    INTO @MyField

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
      SET @current=GetDate()
      SET @datediffernce=datediff(mm, @LastChangeDate , @current)
      //Something here , i cant seem to get the l_date and make some algo on it and then change its status.
      FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
      INTO @MyField 
    END; 

    CLOSE @MyCursor ;
    DEALLOCATE @MyCursor;
END;

GO
```

Any kind of help is appreciated , Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using sql server, if you find yourself using cursors you're probably doing it wrong!

```
UPDATE [login credentials]
SET status = 'inactive'
WHERE datediff(mm,l_date,getdate())>=3
```

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't you just use `update`?

```
update login_credentials
    set status = 'inactive'
    where l_date < dateadd(month, 3, getdate());
```

It is much better to use set-based operations than cursors.  Not only is performance much better, but the code is shorter, easier to write, and easier to understand.

This version allows the database to take advantage of an index on `login_credentials(l_date)`.  You should know that these do different things:

```
datediff(month, @LastChangeDate , @current)
l_date < dateadd(month, 3, getdate())
```

The first counts the number of month differences between the two dates.  The second subtracts three months from the current date.  According to the text in your question, you really want the second version.